# How to I bulk remove pages using a wildcard search from Safari History on OS X?

Tags: macos, safari

I changed jobs recently and I hate having the auto-complete to bring me addresses that I don't really need and I want to remove the entire domain from my history and books marks?

Like removing `*.acme.com/*` from history and optionally bookmarks.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Bring up your History, enter a search parameter, highlight what's returned and press delete. Same for Bookmarks too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort the problem out, what I was missing was the search button which seems to be very small in located in the bottom-right corner, instead of the top-right like in all other windows.

Comment: Does it really matter where the Search windows is located since pressing ⌘F brings up and or sets focus to the Search windows and one can just start typing after pressing ⌘F.